# LINQPad DB2 Support

Tags: c#, db2, linqpad

I know that I am able to connect LINQPad to an EF Model and be able to run queries to get results and lambda expressions back, but for DB2, it does not show any SQL due to the provider not being handed over to LINQPad by EF. It seems that if I want to be able to see the SQL, I need to write a custom driver for DB2 to get it to work. I have read the documentation and it is a bit over my head. Does anyone have an example of this working, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I could really use this too.  I had some idea what was going on before when I used the EF Tracing Provider, but other requirements mean that I can't use a wrapped provider right now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the LightSpeed driver for LinqPad?  It claims to have support for DB2.  http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2010/03/01/lightspeed-and-linqpad-the-perfect-partners/

Answer (score 0):

I've installed DevExpress's XPO driver .

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument10739

It seems the connection string should be something like

XpoProvider=DB2;Server=MyAddress:MyPortNumber;User ID=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword;Database=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=true

The driver files comes with installing devExpress's trial. So this use might me trial as well.